# Boundary regularity for heat equation

Tags: parabolic-pde, regularity

Consider the heat equation $u_t - \Delta u=0$ with $u = u_0$ on $\partial B \times (0,T) \cup B \times \{t=0\}$. We consider weak solutions $u \in C^0(0,T;L^2(B)) \cap L^2(0,T;u_0 + W_0^{1,2}(B))$ where $B$ is the unit ball.

We assume that $u_0 \in C^0(-T,T;L^2(2B)) \cap L^2(-T,T; W^{1,2}(2B))$. Futhermore, suppose that $u_0(\cdot,t) \in C^{\alpha}$ for every $t \in (-T,T)$ and every $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

Is it true that $u (\cdot,t) \in C^{\alpha}$ for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and almost every $t \in (0,T)$?

What about analogous regularity at the initial boundary and at the corners $\partial B \times \{t=0\}$?

I am looking for references where such boundary regularity questions are studied.